# Add security layer in front of WebApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis-7

We have one web application built on RactJs/Asp.net MVC/WebAPI in single application along with SQL Server in backend. Application is currently 2 tier and is using owin middleware for token based authentication. Application is running perfectly.

There was some security recommendation after application built to convert the app into 3-tier. We proposed to separate UI and API into two application. Proposed control flow will be like this:

1. Static Content (js, images & css)
   Browser Request > IIS
2. Static Views
   Browser Request > IIS > UI App - MVC Controller
3. Data API
   Browser Request > IIS > UI App - Api Controller > Service App - API Controller > DB

This is straight forward and API controller will get data from service app and apply UI logic and return data to view. Since authentication is token based, we can validate authentication at both UI & Service tier. Anti-forgery will be limited to Web Application only.

However, client wants to have another approach. They suggested us bring up a new app (hosted in IIS ) in between browser & existing app.

They want to follow approach:

1. Static Content (js, images & css)
   Browser Request > New App > Existing App
2. Static Views
   Browser Request > IIS New App > Existing App - MVC Controller
3. Data API
   Browser Request > New App > Existing App - Api Controller > DB

They want to have authentication & anti-forgery (and future security implementation) from the new app. If everything goes fine at new app, forward the incoming request to old app.

I am not able to visualize how the request of one web app will be transferred to other web app. Following approach I can think of -

1. Server.Transfer - Once request is passed from security check in one app, we can do server.transfer. But the constraint is both app needs to be on one server, while client says it has to be in different server.
2. Have all controllers method implemented in new app, and make WebRequest from new app with required details (Get/Post/Delete & headers) and return the httpResponse as it is to the browser. Use httpmodule or Owin middleware for security check.

Apporach 2 seems doable for MVC views & API, but then how we will forward the incoming request to static contents (JS, images, css)

What is the best approach / solution to this problem.  Solution need not be a .net / IIS.